# Cross browser styling issue

Tags: html, css

I have a cross browser styling issue where I could need some help:

I have a form submit button which is disabled when clicked. A server side validation takes place until the final result triggers a morph of the button towards some result message. During that time of validation the form looks "crashed", since everything is disabled for a short time. I implemented an css based "activity spinner" just to the right of the button (not inside the button). Afterwards I realized that this works just fine in Chromium, whilst other browsers place the spinner at a different position...

Here is a simplified [fiddler example](http://jsfiddle.net/rju1asL9/2/):

Markup:

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="busy" disabled="disabled">
        Some text on the button
    </button>
</div>
```

Style:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    border: green solid 1px;
}
button.busy::after {
    content: url(http://www.mccookgazette.com/images/icons/spinner16.gif);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Anyone got a simple solution for this without changing the markup and all?

Comment: Where do you want the spinner to be placed exactly?

Comment: @Obsidian Sorry: just right of the button. _Not_ inside, but next to it.

Comment: Which browser is incorrect? looks fine in firefox

Comment: have you tried assigning `position: relative` to the outer div?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan http://jsfiddle.net/rju1asL9/5/ adds the position: relative, no change.

Comment: @Obsidian Looks fine in Chromium and _sometimes_ Firefox (!), does not in Safari, Opera, MS-IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

### FIDDLE

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    border: green solid 1px;
    position:relative; // This is where the below item will be positioned absolutely from.
}
button.busy::after {
    content: url(http://www.mccookgazette.com/images/icons/spinner16.gif);
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 50%; // Center vertically
    margin-top:-10px; //Offset by half height of spinner
}
```

**The absolute postioned element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.**

[image]

Comment: Seems like this works for all browsers. Thanks!
Now I have to start understanding _why_ :-)

Comment: I had the ``position: relative`` in my original code and also tried in in fiddle, that alone does not change anything.

Comment: Did you use top and right to determine where the absolute item will be positioned from?

Comment: OK, got it to work correctly. Your answer is obviously right, I just had to fiddle a little because the real world example is a bit more complex. Thanks!